# How do I get the current NotesDocument using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, lotus-notes

In a Lotus Notes Project it's simple to access the current document automatically in the QueryOpen method for example, extracting it from NotesUIDocument, which is a parameter.

```
Sub Queryopen(Source As Notesuidocument, Mode As Integer, Isnewdoc As Variant, Continue As Variant)

    //Here I get the document
    Dim doc as NotesDocument
    Set doc = Source.document

End Sub
```

How can I do the same, but working on the web, using Javascript? Not necessarily in the QueryOpen method, of course.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? To access "fields" you can simply do a var doc = document.forms[0] ... And access fields by doc.FieldName.value... But in xpages this will be completely different

Comment: @Tode document.forms[0] Works. If you want, post it as answer and I'll set as the best answer

Comment: Just to be clear, accessing the fields through the JavaScript DOM is not the same as accessing the current NotesDocument. It's really more analogous to accessing the current NotesUIDocument and using fieldGetText.

Comment: That's a good point (if one knows the difference between frontend and backend in LotusScript).

Comment: It is much more easy than I thought. I'm new to Lotus Web development, but using JS. Soon I'll be using XPages, which seems to be powerfull and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to access document fields, then it is an easy task to do:

```
var doc = document.forms[0];
var yourfield = doc.YourFieldName; // take care: fieldname is case sensitive
// to get a field- value;
var theValue = yourfield.value;
// to set a field value
yourfield.value = "AnotherValue";
```

In XPages this is done completely different as there you have JavaScript classes with similar / same methods / properties as the NotesDocument- class to mimic the LotusScript behaviour